# Access Parameter Query Enter a Date range from Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, parameters, ms-access-2010

I am using Access 2010 and would like to create a Parameter query where by I can enter the criteria to bring up results in between the used entered date range. The first table is called tblClient:

Plan Name   NameCode 
ABC           DC 
XYX           TA 
DEF           TA 
Y2K           TA 
AMC           DC

The second table is tblworkdate

Date         PlanName     Description
1/6/2014         ABC          Services
2/4/2014         XYX        Follow-Up
2/27/2014        DEF        Services
3/11/2014        Y2K        Follow-Up
5/29/2014        AMC        Services
11/7/2014        ABC        Follow-Up
11/21/2014           XYX        Follow-Up
12/1/2014        DEF        Services
1/2/2015         Y2K        Follow-Up
2/5/2015         AMC          Services
2/26/2015        XYZ        Follow-Up

The two table's connected relationship is "Plan Name" to "PlanName" I would like to create a parameter query where I can enter the date range myself and it will only bring up entries to fall within this range. So for example, if I picked a range from 5/29/2014 to 2/5/2015, it would look something like this:

Date            PlanName        Description       NameCode
5/29/2014         AMC           Services          DC
11/7/2014         ABC           Follow-Up         DC
11/21/2014        XYX           Follow-Up         TA
12/1/2014         DEF           Services          TA
1/2/2015          Y2K           Follow-Up         TA
2/5/2015          AMC           Services          DC

I've tried the regular Between and AND operators but for some reason it only returns 2015 results. Please let me know how to get to something like the above.

Comment: Can you post an example of the SQL that you have already?

Comment: Below is a the sql that I currently have. The main issue here is that while I have both 2014 and 2015 dates in my dataset, it only shows the 2015 results irregardless of the dates that I put into the parameter. How do I correct this syntax?
SELECT Format([Date],"mm/dd/yyyy") AS Expr2, tblClient.NameCode, tblworkdate.Description
FROM tblClient INNER JOIN Entry ON tblClient.[Plan Name] = tblworkdate.PlanName
WHERE (((Format([Date],"mm/dd/yyyy")) Between [Please enter a Beginning Date (mm/dd/yyyy)] And [Please enter an End Date (mm/dd/yyyy)]))

Comment: I'm going to post an answer, but if it doesn't work I'll revise it. It's simply for readibility

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points to discuss.

1: You select [Date], and this is not a built in function in my version of access. Does the user enter 3 dates? Do you want to use the current date?

2: You join something called "Entry" on a value in tblworkdate, which you have not joined to your query. You also select a value from tblworkdate, but you have not joined it.

3: Do you want to use this query with VBA or do you want to prompt a user?

Your query should look something like

```
PARAMETERS [BeginningDate] DateTime, [EndingDate] Datetime;
SELECT Format([Date],"mm/dd/yyyy") AS Expr2, tblClient.NameCode _
FROM tblClient WHERE (((Format([Date],"mm/dd/yyyy")) _
BETWEEN [BeginningDate] AND [EndingDate]
```

Comment: 1) I just want the user to be able to enter a beginning date and end date with the results displaying the dates within that range inclusively.
2)Sorry, I "Entry" is original name for the table  tblworkdate. I changed the names around because this is database from work.
3) I would like to prompt the user to enter in the dates.